# Асинхронная загрузка данных в список

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragment

У меня есть фрагмент, который содержит `ListView`. `ListView` я заполняю адаптером. В новом `Task` я заполняю `ListView`. В самом адаптере у меня стоит проверка на пустоту. Мне нужно вызвать `task` в фрагменте, если список пустой. Я реализовываю вот так:

```
public class FragmentAddFriends extends Fragment {

    View v;
    ListView listView;
    public ArrayList<myFriend> myFriendArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> friendses = new ArrayList<>();
    AddFriendsAdapter adapter;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    getAddFriendsTask task;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_friends_fragment,container,false);
        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listViewAddFriends);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);

        adapter = new AddFriendsAdapter(getActivity(),myFriendArrayList);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //VKRequest zapros = VKApi.friends().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID, Integer.parseInt(VKAccessToken.currentToken().userId),VKApiConst.FIELDS,"photo_50"));
        task =  new getAddFriendsTask();
        task.execute();
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        task.cancel(true);
    }

    public void update(){
        task.execute();
        button.setVisibility(View.Visible);
    }
}
```

При повторном вызове метода в фрагменте список дополняется. Вот так я в адаптере вызываю:

```
if(list.size()==0){
    fragment.update();
}
```

Но при этом вызов метода осуществляется, но список не обновляется. И кнопка так же не становится видимой.

Comment: вам нужно узнать о классе `Loader` и [его потомках](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/loader.php) (как `AsyncTaskLoader`). Они специально предназначены для асинхронного заполнения списков.

Comment: @pavlofff, хорошо, с AsynsTaskLoader я разберусь, а чего тогда кнопка не становится видимой?

Comment: Возможно, ошибка в том, как у вас описан layout. Покажите add_friends_fragment.xml